# JavaFX Listener to check for a boolean value

Tags: java, javafx, properties, boolean, bind

I have a game with a GUI with a couple of buttons that you press to eventually complete the game.

*I have the following boolean to test:*

```
public boolean complete(){
    if (initvalue==finalvaue)){
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I want to create a listener to check if the game is finished and to print out a message to the user. I think I need to create a `SimpleBooleanProperty` for this to work. But would I need to bind it to the boolean value above?

What would the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 6):

You can have a [`BooleanProperty`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/property/BooleanProperty.html) called `completedProperty` and you can have `initvalueProperty` and `finalValueProperty` also to store the points of the game, and then you can simply bind the value of the `completedProperty` like

```
completedProperty.bind(initValueProperty.isEqualTo(finalValueProperty));
```

therefore you don't even need a method anymore.

In the example I have just placed a `Button` which increments the current value by one on press and I used 3 properties to continuously check the "game" state. As soon as the `completedProperty` switches to "true", a `Label` with text of *"Game Over*" appears.

**Note:** I have used [`IntegerProperty`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/property/IntegerProperty.html) to store the current and the final value, but you can use any [`Property`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/property/Property.html).

**Example:**

```
public class Main extends Application {

    private IntegerProperty initValueProperty = new SimpleIntegerProperty(0);
    private IntegerProperty finalValueProperty = new SimpleIntegerProperty(10);
    private BooleanProperty completedProperty = new SimpleBooleanProperty();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);

            Button buttonPlusOne = new Button("+1");
            root.setCenter(buttonPlusOne);

            Text currValueText = new Text();
            currValueText.textProperty().bind(initValueProperty.asString());
            root.setBottom(currValueText);

            // Increment current value
            buttonPlusOne.setOnAction(e -> initValueProperty.set(initValueProperty.get()+1));
            // Bind completed property: initValue equals finalValue
            completedProperty.bind(initValueProperty.isEqualTo(finalValueProperty));

            completedProperty.addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                // Only if completed
                if (newValue) 
                    root.setTop(new Label("Game Over"));
            });

            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Optionally (as noted by [fabian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2991525/fabian)) you can even use a [`BooleanBinding`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/BooleanBinding.html) rather than a property to check the completed state (in this case you don't need `completedProperty`), like:

```
BooleanBinding completed = initValueProperty.isEqualTo(finalValueProperty);
completed.addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    // Only if completed
    if (newValue) 
        root.setTop(new Label("Game Over"));
});
```

To learn about properties in JavaFX [this is a really good article](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/properties-binding-tutorial/binding.htm) to start with.

Comment: Note that none of this actually requires a `BooleanProperty`. Everything done here could also be done using the [BooleanBinding](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/BooleanBinding.html) returned by `isEqualTo` directly... Furthermore here's the link for version 8: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/properties-binding-tutorial/binding.htm (probably contains the same content).

Comment: Yes, that is absolutely true, I just felt it is cleaner to introduce bindings like this and then as the OP gets more and more familiar with the topic he can explore it himself :) Btw, I will include it in the answer (also the link update).

Comment: So with the boolean binding, would I need to change the boolean method I  had originally. Do I even need to bind? Can I not even just set a simplebooleanproperty to the original boolean code then just use addlistener to see when it changes?

Comment: You can even set the `completedProperty` in your current method of course, the point is: that is a property so it is observable, so you can add a listener to be notified about the changes. The example just shows that if you use properties extensively, you don't even need to call a method whereever you modify the current value, as the binding ensures that the `completedProperty` always has the correct value.

Comment: My issue is that the initValue and finalValue are strings that are changing with the game.

The initValue is the one that constantly changes. How would I go back and change the Strings to SimpleStringProperty

Comment: And I tried to bind to the original boolen, which then told be to convert it to an observable value which caused the rest of the program to mess up.

Comment: With `StringPoperty` the workflow is the same. And I don't understand "And I tried to bind to the original boolen". You asked how shall you perform, and that question became answered. I don't see your full code so I cannot tell you what is "messed up" now. But I think it is a good practice for yourself to play a bit with properties as they are really extensively used (not just in JavaFX).

Comment: Remember that in the last example object `completed` can be garbage collected if you don't store the reference!